# Facebook keyword search deprecated

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I recently came to know that the Facebook keyword search has been deprecated. What are the alternative ways by which I could get timeline data for a particluar keyword. For example: I want all facebook posts for the keyword "ronaldo". How could I achieve this in the new API v2.3?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean "Public Post search"? There is no alternative way, but you can take a look at those APIs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/keyword_insights
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed

Comment: yup. you have to ask one of those partners for access.